# How to appendString with spacing in between

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've got my 1st string and 2nd string by using appendString method, the result will be `AB`. I wanted to give a gap in between to display as `A, B`.

```
scanPackage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result.text];

NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:savedString];
[string appendString:scanPackage];

//Saved into memory
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[preferences setObject:string forKey:@"scanResult"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array can do it without manipulated the string, can add more in the array to combine:

```
NSString *combined = [@[savedString, scanPackage] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSString` function `stringByAppendingFormat:`.  Try this.

```
scanPackage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result.text];
NSString *string = [savedString stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@",scanPackage];
//Saved into memory
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[preferences setObject:string forKey:@"scanResult"];
```